# Node.js error: too many parameters Error while uploading bulk data

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

I have a task to upload user data in bulk through csv file. I am using `nodejs` and `express` framework. When i submit csv file having 60 to 70 rows it works fine, but when it exceeds 70 rows it starts giving server error too many parameters. After some research i concluded that it may be the problem of body parser size, so i tried [This blog](http://blog.matthewdfuller.com/2014/10/nodejs-error-too-many-parameters-at.html) , but it didnt worked error is still same.

here is my code for body parser:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Error message:

```
2016-04-19T10:29:45.299Z - error: [req#d3a1fa1a-278e-496e-9cb1-b3a944e3d1c8/app] [App] Error: too many parameters Error: too many parameters
    at queryparse (d:\Git\gap-vm 13416\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:119:17)
    at parse (d:\Git\gap-vm 13416\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:64:9)
    at d:\Git\gap-vm 13416\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:91:18
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (d:\Git\gap-vm 13416\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:136:7)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:906:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)
```

So , can anyone tell me where i am going wrong. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanx in advance.

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 27):

As others mention, you'll need to set the `parameterLimit` to deal with the "too many parameters" error. You may also need to set the `limit` to a larger size to avoid a load size error. In the case of CSV, the urlencoded limits will be applied, but others may also want to set the JSON limits too. The following setting will work unless there are other places in the code that are overriding these settings:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 1000000}));
```

Comment: Set parameterLimit as option of bodyParser.json() is wrong. Look https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions

Comment: Agreed. I removed parameterLimit from bodyParser.json()

Answer (score 9):

In your code it you are not using the `parameterLimit`at all, as pointed out as in the blog posted you linked.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: false,
    parameterLimit: 1000000 // experiment with this parameter and tweak
}));
```

Comment: @ Francesco actually i tried this code before , but it was not working so i reverted it to original.Above code not working .

Comment: Did you try setting both `limit`and `parameterLimit` for your `bodyParser.urlencoded` middleware?
According to [body-parser docs](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions), there are only 5 settings available: `inflate`, `limit`, `parameterLimit`, `type`, `verify`

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure where you guys are testing your API but for me it was because I set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in Postman. Once I removed the header and used `form-data` under the body section, it solved the issue. Make sure to always use `form-data` when uploading files. 
Hope it helps...