# Payload too large entity add error node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am working on elastic search in node.js. When I try to add my users in elastic search using node.js then I receive following exception all the time. One thing is considerable is that 15000 users successfully update but when user limit increase from 15000 then I receive following exception from node.js

```
    'PayloadTooLargeError: too many parameters\n    
at queryparse (/home/rizwan/php/elastic-search-node/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:151:13)\n   
 at parse (/home/rizwan/php/elastic-search-node/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:75:9)\n   
 at /home/rizwan/php/elastic-search-node/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18\n    
at invokeCallback (/home/rizwan/php/elastic-search-node/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)\n    
at done (/home/rizwan/php/elastic-search-node/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)\n    
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/rizwan/php/elastic-search-node/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)\n   
 at emitNone (events.js:106:13)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)\n   
 at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)\n    
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)\n    
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)'
```

Comment: Please set the limit in body parse in your application. Check if below link helps you
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716311/node-js-error-too-many-parameters-error-while-uploading-bulk-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716311/node-js-error-too-many-parameters-error-while-uploading-bulk-data)

Comment: @SagarGopale I already set this below is my code
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

Comment: I see. But did you check the below part in the link I provided. The "parameterLimit" option.

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: false,
    parameterLimit: 1000000 // experiment with this parameter and tweak
}));`

Comment: @SagarGopale no success still same exception

Comment: How are you trying to add the users? What is the request format and the headers you are sending in the request?

Comment: 24443 users are in the requests and header requests are
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.get('Origin'));
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Cache-Control, Pragma");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

Comment: I was asking about the headers you send when calling the request not the one you set in response and are the users url-encoded or json. Give the complete info of the API. That will help us debug the issue.

Comment: @SagarGopale { host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
  'user-agent': 'Guzzle/4.2.4 curl/7.35.0 PHP/7.0.26-2+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+2',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'content-length': '476162' }

Comment: Ok. Try changing content-type header's value to form-data instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded and let me know if it works.