# How can I change the limit of max size of package for a POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I am trying to send an array of bytes with a POST request. I am using Node.js and Express.js for the server side. I get error code 413 or the page even freezes ('PayloadTooLargeError: too many parameters').

My variable base64 looks like this:

data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAYGBgYHBgcICAcKCwoLCg8ODAwODxYQERAREBYiFRkVFRkVIh4kHhweJB42KiYmKjY+NDI0PkxERExfWl98fKcBBgYGBgcGBwgIBwoLCgsKDw4MDA4PFhAREBEQFiIVGRUVGRUiHiQeHB4kHjYqJiYqNj40MjQ+TERETF9aX3x8p//CABEIBLAGQAMBIgACEQEDEQH/x...

My variable bytes looks like this:

Uint8Array(294508) [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 132, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 15, 14, 12, 12, 14, 15, 22, 16, 17, 16, 17, 16, 22, 34, 21, 25, 21, 21, 25, 21, 34, 30, 36, 30, 28, 30, 36, 30, 54, 42, 38, 38, 42, 54, 62, 52, 50, 52, 62, 76, 68, 68, 76, 95, 90, 95, 124, 124, 167, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8, 7, …]

I tried to set in app.js the limit with body-parser and below is my POST request:

```
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

```
    <input onchange="openFile(event)" type="file" id="FileUpload">
```

```
    function openFile(event) {

        var input = event.target;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
            var base64 = reader.result;
            var bytea = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64); //This converts to bytea

            $.post('/user/update', {username: user.firstname, profilePicture: bytea}, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    alert(err);
                } else {
                    alert("Miracle");
                }
            });
        };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

I expect that the package reaches the server and stores the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js error: too many parameters Error while uploading bulk data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716311/node-js-error-too-many-parameters-error-while-uploading-bulk-data)

Comment: You might be correct. I tried with parameterLimit but it still woudn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the contentLength in your post request. Maybe the default value is small due to which it cannot send the whole data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the array of bytes, I am sending the base64 and this solved the problem. The error was caused from the array. Probably I can solved the problem adding parameterLimit as suggested here
[Node.js error: too many parameters Error while uploading bulk data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716311/node-js-error-too-many-parameters-error-while-uploading-bulk-data)